# Bug in Code Contracts 1.4.40602.0 when Generic and Non-Generic method have the same name and parameters?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-contracts

The Contracts for the Generic method is getting lost and does not show up in the IL.  Below is a code example.  If you just removed the non-generic from the interface then the generic contract works as expected.  But with the non-generic in place the generic contract is getting lost in the re-write.

```
[ContractClass(typeof(IContractTestContract))]
interface IContractTest
{
    string TestMethod(string arg);
    T TestMethod<T>(string arg);
}    
[ContractClassFor(typeof(IContractTest))]
abstract class IContractTestContract : IContractTest
{
    public string TestMethod(string arg)
    {
        Contract.Requires(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(arg));
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public T TestMethod<T>(string arg)
    {
        Contract.Requires(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(arg));
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
class ContractTest : IContractTest
{
    public string TestMethod(string arg) { return null; }
    public T TestMethod<T>(string arg) { return default(T); }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var c = new ContractTest();
        //Does not fail static or runtime checks
        //Contract is getting lost
        c.TestMethod<string>(null);
    }
}
```

Code Contract Settings
[image: Settings]

Comment: Have you tried enabling 'Call-site Requires Checking'? It might have a different behavior since contracts get built into callers.

Comment: I just tried 'Call-site Requires Checking' and it has the same behavior, the contracts are getting lost and no static or runtime error.  And yes I have reported this issue to Microsoft. [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/712865/bug-in-code-contracts-1-4-40602-0-when-generic-and-non-generic-method-have-the-same-name-and-parameters) [Code Contract Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/codecontracts/thread/c74d7aa0-d7ed-47eb-9f5c-543a3b2a5a70)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has confirmed this as a bug in code contracts and it's already fixed internally.  It will be released in an up coming public build.

[Microsoft Ticket](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/712865/bug-in-code-contracts-1-4-40602-0-when-generic-and-non-generic-method-have-the-same-name-and-parameters)